# Custom BufferGeometry in react-three-fiber

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

I want to make a custom geometry using react-three-fiber.
I am new to three.js and at first completed this great tutorial: https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-custom-buffergeometry.html
All went well, but then I decided to fascilitate my app with react.
I couldn't figure out how to declaratively create a custom shape. All I found on the official API was:

```
<bufferGeometry attach="geometry">
  <bufferAttribute attachObject={['attributes', 'position']} count={v.length / 3} array={v} itemSize={3} />
```

So I tried it with the basic example from here: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry

```
const vertices = new Float32Array( [
    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
     1.0, -1.0,  1.0,
     1.0,  1.0,  1.0,

     1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0,  1.0,  1.0,
    -1.0, -1.0,  1.0
] );
```

The above code is located inside a custom functional component, which is put on the canvas.
The return statement looks like this:

```
  return (
    <mesh>
      <bufferGeometry>
        <bufferAttribute
          attachObject={["attributes", "position"]}
          array={vertices}
          itemSize={3}
        />
      </bufferGeometry>
      <meshNormalMaterial />
    </mesh>
  );
```

But nothing displays.
How do you create custom geometry from arrays of coordinates and normals using react-three-fiber?

Comment: The same as in three, you can either sick plain new buffergeom() into useState/use memo or create it declaratively like you did. I think the count prop  is missing though.

Comment: Yes you are right, I forgot to add `count` prop.
And another mistake was not converting another my testing array of positions to `Float32Array`.
But I got another question.
If I provide my own set of normals, all is fine.
But how do you call `geometry.computeVertexNormals()` when working declaratively?

Comment: this is a side-effect. in react everything is managed. you would put a ref onto the mesh or geom and then call it inside useLayoutEffect. Layout because this one allows you to mutate *before* it actually renders on screen. useEffect would trigger afterwards.

Comment: hpalu, thank you, it helped

Comment: Hello....Cloud hpalu or agt-ru share a code snippet or a clodepen example on creating a custom shape by using vertex and joining lines  by react-three-fiber.  Also, how one can select the shape using a mouse?   Im absolutely new to three-fiber  and learning from you guyes....  Alternate, please provide a link where I can see this as a Demo....

Answer (score 0):

I think you're very close, it could be that it didn't work because the indices are missing.

Also `attachObject` is deprecated in favour of `attach='attributes-position'` etc.

Here's a simple example:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { DoubleSide } from 'three'

const positions = new Float32Array([
    1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0,
    -1, 0, 0,
    0, -1, 0
])

const normals = new Float32Array([
    0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 1,
])

const colors = new Float32Array([
    0, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1,
])

const indices = new Uint16Array([
    0, 1, 3,
    2, 3, 1,
])

const Comp = () =>
    <mesh>
        <bufferGeometry>
            <bufferAttribute
                attach='attributes-position'
                array={positions}
                count={positions.length / 3}
                itemSize={3}
            />
            <bufferAttribute
                attach='attributes-color'
                array={colors}
                count={colors.length / 3}
                itemSize={3}
            />
            <bufferAttribute
                attach='attributes-normal'
                array={normals}
                count={normals.length / 3}
                itemSize={3}
            />
            <bufferAttribute
                attach="index"
                array={indices}
                count={indices.length}
                itemSize={1}
            />
        </bufferGeometry>
        <meshStandardMaterial
            vertexColors
            side={DoubleSide}
        />
    </mesh>
```

For extra reading [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kTQZVzkXgI) covers animating attributes.