# BufferGeometry normals react-three-fiber

Tags: shadow, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to create custom shapes. I've created a triangle, but I'm struggling to create normals in order to have the material reflect shadows. In another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67555786/custom-buffergeometry-in-react-three-fiber) using useLayoutEffect was the suggested soltuion. How is this done?

```
 const mesh = useRef<THREE.Mesh>(null!);

 const vertices = new Float32Array( [
    point1.x, point1.y, point1.z,
    point2.x, point2.y, point2.z,
    point3.x, point3.y, point3.z,
  ] );  


  return (
    <mesh
      ref={mesh}
      position={[position.x, position.y, position.z]}
    >
      <bufferGeometry attach="geometry">
          <bufferAttribute
              attachObject={["attributes", "position"]}
              array={vertices}
              count={vertices.length / 3}
              itemSize={3}
                />
        </bufferGeometry>
        <meshPhongMaterial color={color} side={THREE.DoubleSide} />
    </mesh>
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with:

```
onUpdate={self => self.computeVertexNormals()}
```

I'm a complete beginner on React and ThreeJs so i'm not sure yet how hooks etc should be used for effiency.

```
    <mesh
      ref={mesh}
      position={[position.x, position.y, position.z]}
       >
      <bufferGeometry attach="geometry" onUpdate={self => self.computeVertexNormals()}>
          <bufferAttribute
              attachObject={["attributes", "position"]}
              array={vertices}
              count={vertices.length / 3}
              itemSize={3}
                />
        </bufferGeometry>
        <meshPhongMaterial color={color} side={THREE.DoubleSide} />
    </mesh>
```

Comment: I was setting my vertices manually and had a flickering of lighting working/not. Setting the onUpdate as you specified resolved the issue. Thanks for the code sample!